# How to hide previous on first page and next on last page in jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, pagination

I use the jquery library in order to display a sql result.
On the first page of the datatable the previous button is by default deactivated. However I want it to be hidden, same goes for the next button on the last page.

As it is deactivated automatically I was thinking that there might be a parameter or sth to hide it instead, however I was not finding much during my research.

My table looks like this:

```js
    $('#userTable').DataTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/> 
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="userTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>heading1</th>
    <th>heading2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>element11</td>
    <td>element12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>element21</td>
    <td>element22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>element31</td>
    <td>element32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>elementN1</td>
    <td>elementN2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: so, can you post your question like this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't have any code which is trying to solve the problem because I don't know how to do it!?

Comment: you don't have any html and jquery that you can show? even the datatable isn't coded by you?

Comment: ok, of course I have some "SourceCode" - it just does not try to solve the described problem so far, that's why I did not put any sourcecode with it - because I thought my text helps much more... However I now added the code.

Comment: maybe you can take some time to read the documentation of jquery datatables  https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info() 
with that, you can get some info and then work with some `'if` and adjust the table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have managed it by using the following code to my `CSS` file:

```
 .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled,
 .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:hover,
 .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled:active
 {
    display:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTable has a **language** option for overriding default values. For the previous and next values, you may add this option when generating the table

```
...,
language: {
  paginate: {
  previous: 'My previous',
  next: 'My next'
  }
},
```

**Note//**
If you just need the carets without any text, you can try this

```
...,
language: {
  paginate: {
    previous: `<span class='hidden></span>`,
    next: `<span class='hidden></span>`
  }
},
```

And add some css (I am using sass for this).

```
  .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
    &.next,
    &.previous {
      cursor: pointer;
      a {
        display: none;
      }
      &.disabled {
        cursor: not-allowed;
      }
    }
  }

  .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.next {
    &::after {
      padding-left: 12px;
    }
  }
```